# docker-compose containers uses wrong container with multiple projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two projects and I need two differents docker environnement (containers). I have two `docker-compose.yml` files in two different projects. `foo` project and `bar` project.

`foo/src/website/docker-compose.yml` #1 (`foo`)

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    env_file: .env
    image: mariadb:10.0.23
    container_name: foo-db
    ports:
      - "42333:3306"
    restart: always
  web:
    image: project/foo
    container_name: foo-web
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/webapps/foo
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`bar/src/website/docker-compose.yml` #2 (`bar`)

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.5.50
    container_name: bar-db
    ports:
      - "42333:3306"
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
  web:
    image: project/bar
    container_name: bar-web
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/webapps/bar
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I do this command for my `foo` project `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, everything works. In Kitematic I see my two containers with the good names (`foo-web`).

1. I do this command to stop my image `docker-compose stop`.
2. I go to my second project (`bar`) and run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. everything works, but my container name in now replaced by `bar-web`.
3. I stop my second image with `docker-compose stop` and I try to perform `docker-compose up` in my `foo` project folder again but it fails.

**How can I keep two different containers and easily switch from one to the other with `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose up`?**

### Edit 1

I found the issue, the main folder where my `docker-compose.yml` are located for my two projects have the same folder name. Can I fix this or I need to rename my folders?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the directory name is the default project name for `docker-compose`:

```
$ docker-compose --help
  ...
  -p, --project-name NAME    Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)
```

Use the `-p` argument to specify a particular non-default project name.

Alternatively, you can also set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable (which defaults to the `basename` of the project directory).

If you are sharing compose configurations between files and projects with multiple compose files, refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) link for more info.

Comment: you saved my life...
using deployer or any other online deploy tool  on remote server basically I've hundreds projects using same folder name es:  "projectname/releases/1"
in this context using a .env specifing COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=projectname  was fundamental

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution

```
docker-compose -p projectname build 
docker-compose -p projectname up
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the ports. As you define public ports, each container must have its own. So in your second project, change the ports of the db and web (42334 and 3001 for example).

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try your solution bit I got the same issue, container from my first project is replaced by second project container name.

Comment: Try to remove container_name every where.

Comment: Same issue, look my edit #1, I found the problem... But I need to know I would like to know if I can fix this or if a absolutely need to rename my folders.